# TCP connection to ESP8266 via WiFiClient.h from Android phone

Tags: tcp, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I looking for clarification on how the WiFiClient and WiFiServer objects in [this example ESP8266 sketch](https://github.com/roboremo/ESP8266-WiFi-UART-Bridge/blob/master/sketch_esp_WiFi_UART_Bridge.ino) starts a TCP connection and allows an Android app to read and write to buffers that's setup in the sketch.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
WiFiServer server(port);
WiFiClient client;

uint8_t buf1[1024];

server.begin(); // start TCP server  
client = server.available(); // wait for it to connect

buf1[i1] = (uint8_t)client.read(); // read char from client (RoboRemo app)
client.write((char*)buf2, i2);
```

This sketch talks to a closed-source Android app call Roboremo.  It uses *WiFiServer* to create a TCP server, and *WiFiClient* to read/write to buffers.  What is this TCP server, and what mechanism is being used to read/write to the ESP8266?  So, if I were having a conversation with an app developer, how do I tell them how to write to this TCP server (other than IP and port number)?  Is this a "TCP socket", and does that translate into something that mobile app people would know how to proceed?

Another way to ask this question:  I'd like to be able to test read/write to the ESP8266 without the Android app.  So if I have a Raspberry Pi on the same network as this ESP8266, what utility (mechanism again) can I use to read/write to those buffers from the Pi?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the Roboremo sketch shows that you will be working with esp8266 on STA mode by providing your ssid and pass into the sketch. That means you need to find the ip address of esp8266 before making a connection. A ridiculous comment from sketch is :

> Then somehow find the IP that the ESP got from router

So, if you will continue with STA mode, you may go to your router settings and find the ESP8266 from DHCP clients.

For a raspberry TCP client connection, you need nothing else from a Linux socket client. Here a basic python client to test on raspberry :

```
import socket
import sys

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
except socket.error, msg:
    print 'Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit();

print 'Socket Created'

host = 'YOUR_ESP8266_IP '
port = 9876

s.connect((remote_ip , port))

print 'Socket Connected to ' + host

#Send some data to remote server
message = "test esp8266 server"

try :
    s.sendall(message)
except socket.error:
    print 'Send failed'
    sys.exit()

print 'Message send successfully'
```